# How to use sed to replace a token in a file with multiple lines?

Tags: sed

I'd like to automate the insertion of text into a specified location in a configuration file, and I'd like to do it via the use of a token. For example:

```
Existing text
%% NEW_CONTENT
Existing text
```

What I'd like to do is to use `sed` to identify the `%% NEW_CONTENT` and to insert at least one line of text in front. The new file will then have:

```
Existing text
New line 1
New line 2
%% NEW_CONTENT
Existing text
```

I cannot figure out how to replace one line with multiple lines, however. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sed '/%% NEW_CONTENT/iNew line 1\nNew line 2' inputfile
```

Comment: POSIX sed complains and wants `i` to be followed by space backslash.

Comment: Too awesome. Thanks.